# Search in members of array of data structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, binary-search

I have an array of this data structure:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned long id; // Node identification
char *name;
double lat, lon; // Node position
} node;
```

And I want to do a binary search through the **id**.
I tried defining the function like this

```
unsigned long bi_search(unsigned long *Vector, unsigned long Vlen, unsigned long target) {
    imin = 0; imax = Vlen-1;
    while (imax > imin) {
        imid = (imax + imin)/2;
        if (Vector[imid] == target) {
            return imid;
        }
        else if (Vector[imid] < target) {
            imin = imid + 1;
        }
        else {
            imax = imid - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And calling it with

```
bi_search(&nodes->id, nnodes, 0)
```

The function works for a vector, but I'm not able to make it work to search inside an array of structures.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are making a fundamental error: `nodes` is a pointer to the first element in an array of `node`, and `&nodes->id` is a pointer to the `id` member of that `node` (which is an `unsigned long`) but it is **not** a pointer to the first element in an array on `unsigned long`.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and for you answer :D
Yes that's exactly the problem, do you have an idea how to make it work.

Comment: Instead of `Vector[imid] == target`, use `Vector[imid].id == target`, and likewise for `Vector[imid] < target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the signature of your search function and the way you call it.
You have to take a pointer to the first element of an array of the structure type.  Inside the function, you'll use `vector[i].id` to access the `id` member of the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the array.

```
unsigned long bi_search(node *vector, unsigned long vlen, unsigned long target)
{
    unsigned long imin = 0;
    unsigned long imax = vlen - 1;
    while (imax > imin)
    {
        unsigned long imid = (imax + imin) / 2;
        if (vector[imid].id == target)
            return imid;
        else if (vector[imid].id < target)
            imin = imid + 1;
        else
            imax = imid - 1;
    }
    return ULONG_MAX;  // -1 isn't an option
}
```

You then call it with the start of the array:

```
unsigned long index = bi_search(nodes, nnodes, 0);
```